# How can I specify units other than pixels in javascript using scrollTo, scrollTop etc.?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, units-of-measurement

I have an entire website built using **REMs instead of pixels**.

The site is built to be 40% wider than the window, so 20% of the page is hidden on either side.

Consequently, I need to find a way to **scroll horizontally when the page is loaded** so that it will be centered.

The **page is 140 rem** wide, the **window is 100rem** wide.

So I could set scrollLeft to 20% or 20rem, but when I use:

```
document.body.scrollLeft = '20rem';
```

it doesn't work. I've tried many other things with no luck.

**Is it possible to use units other than pixels to control scrolling?**

I would *really* prefer not to add an object to the page and have to scroll to the object.

Comment: How can you know that the window is 100rem wide?

Comment: I define it that way so I can use REM everywhere and have the window stay exactly the same: var pixel = (window.innerWidth)/100; document.documentElement.style.fontSize = pixel+'px'; Example at http://files.ozake.com/responsive_example/

Comment: I see. In that case, I'd say use your `pixel` to convert REM values to pixels and pass that to all `scroll*` values, as already suggested in an answer. It's a pixel world we live in, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

Write a converter that takes REM values and converts them to pixels. Then just get the pixel value for a given REM value and throw the pixel value into the scroll function.

Comment: I did write a program to solve this question but I wanted to know if there was a way to set the value directly without having to convert anything. A bunch of Googling turned up nothing, so I guess it's impossible. But I'd like to be sure.